# Tinymce Image upload - save to database

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have configured my TinyMCE to use **images_upload_url** and **images_upload_handler** to post to a selected image to a server-side page which saves the image to a location on my server. In addition, this server-side page also saves the filename of the image as a record within a database.

I then have another server-side page which reads the database and constructs a JSON list of the images that have been uploaded. This JSON data is then pulled into my Tinymce instance using **image_list**, so that I can easily reuse previously uploaded images as opposed to having to reupload the same image more than once.

The specific lines of my **tiny.init()** are:

```
image_list: 'processes/image-list.php',
image_class_list: [
    {title: 'None', value: ''},
    {title: 'Full width image', value: 'img-responsive'}
  ],
images_upload_url: 'processes/upload-image.php',
images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
    var xhr, formData;
  
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = false;
    xhr.open('POST', 'processes/upload-image-free.asp');
  
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var json;
    
        if (xhr.status != 200) {
            failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
            return;
        }
    
        json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    
        if (!json || typeof json.location != 'string') {
            failure('Invalid JSON: ' + xhr.responseText);
            return;
        }
    
        success(json.location);
    };
  
    formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());
  
    xhr.send(formData);
},
image_dimensions: false,
```

***All of this works as expected.***

What I would like to do is also save a description of the image to the database so this can be outputted as the title within the JSON data of previously uploaded images.

As the upload feature only allows an image to be selected from a file system I cannot utilise the upload feature:
[image]

So I thought I could utilise the **alternate description** field of the image feature/modal but this would have to be done via a JavaScript triggered event that is triggered upon submitting the image feature/modal, that takes the content in the alternative description input field and POST this to a serverside page that can update the database.

Unless there is another way does anybody know how I can target the 'click' on the 'save' button within the image feature to extract the alternate description before the image feature/modal disappears and extract the input field content?

From there I should be able to work out how to get this to a server-side page to update the database.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to resolve this so posting a solution to help others - though this is more than a hack.

Firstly on my form page after the tiny.init is loaded I am using the following:

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', logKey);

  function logKey(e) {
    labels = document.querySelectorAll(".tox-label");
    for (i = 0; i < labels.length; ++i) {
      if (labels[i].textContent == "Alternative description"){
        imageDescription = document.getElementById(labels[i].htmlFor).value;
      }
    }
  };
```

This loops through all the elements (labels in this case) which have a class of .toxlabel and if the textContent matches "Alternative description" then to capture the value in in a variable called 'imageDescription'.

Then within my tiny.init I have the following:

```
editor.on('ExecCommand', function(e) {
        if (e.command == "mceUpdateImage"){
            var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var params = encodeURI('desc=' + imageDescription);
            http.open('POST', 'processes/upload-image-description.asp', true);

            http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

            http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
                if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                    console.log(http.responseText);
                }
            }
            http.send(params);
        }
      });
```

This code is actioned upon the mceUpdateImage modal closing, it takes the value stored within the imageDescription variable and posts it to a server-side page which updates the database.

I am sure there are cleaner ways but they would require more of a TinyMce understanding.